# Granting advanced users right to directly run SQL queries

Tags: mysql, symfony

I'm developping an application in which you manage a wide variety of data stored in many different tables, using Symfony and Doctrine. I implemented a simple (complex enough) search form for 90% of the usecases, but the problem is the last 10%, which can be some very hard, complex and twisted queries.

My thought was to implement a way for advanced users to write some DQL (SQL dialiect used in Doctrine) queries to run, only of `SELECT`, and make them availables for the rest of users, which would avoid having to code them and push them but rather make them dynamic and extendable. The queries would be stored in database, and the user could be given the chance to change some parameters of the query to make it fits his needs.

I know this needs some advanced security checks but is this solution acceptable?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already part of the symfony console which allow you to run DQL Queries.

1. Get the entity manager
2. $query=$em->createQuery($dql)
3. $resultset=$query->execute($parameters);
4. Render $resultset

For a more complete solution check: vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/RunDqlCommand.php

```
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        /* @var $em \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface */
        $em = $this->getHelper('em')->getEntityManager();

        [...]

        $query = $em->createQuery($dql);

        [...]

        $resultSet = $query->execute([...]);

        // Show the results
    }
```